# What does git branches and trunk folder mean?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

[image: Git folders]

Someone has share this source code with me. Which include three folders 
.Git, branches and trunk.

I am familiar with git but usually when we take git clone we get two folders one of source code and one is .git folder inside that.
I need to know that what does these folders mean and which one contain the actual source code.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the code used to be in Subversion and hasn't been properly converted to git. :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before git was so popular, many people use subversion (svn). In subversion the versioning is linear (revision 10, revision 11, and so on), there is no "inherent" branch and tag. Using these structure is the conventional way to do branching and tagging:

```
awesome-repository/
  trunk/
    README
    code.c
  branches/
    feature1/
      README
      code.c
    feature2/
      README
      code.c
    ...
  tags/
    v0.1/
      README
      code.c
    v0.2/
      README
      code.c
    ...
```

So, probably it is copied from subversion based repository to git based repository. And **usually**:

- `master` branch in git is in `trunk/` directory in subversion
- other branches in git are in `branches/*/` directories in subversion
- tags in git are in `tags/*/` directories in subversion

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: which folder should I checkout to see the codebase?

Comment: @Simer usually they are in `trunk/`; unless you want a specific branch, they are in `branches/something/`